# Asymptotic growth of a function containing a sum

Tags: time-complexity, landau-notation, big-o-notation

How to compare the asymptotic growth of a function containing a sum with another function? I'm not sure how I'm supposed to dissolve the sum. Usually I just take the limis of f(x)/g(x). If that fails I take the limis of f'(x)/g'(x). But I'm not sure what to do in the following task (to prove whether the marked statement is true or not): [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an explicit formula for $\sum_{i=0}^n i^3$, but even without it, you can estimate
$$
\int_0^n x^3 \, dx \leq \sum_{i=0}^n i^3 \leq \int_1^{n+1} x^3 \, dx.
$$
Since $\int x^3 \, dx = x^4/4$, this shows that the sum is very close to $n^4/4$, and in particular is $\Theta(n^4)$.

(The explicit formula states that the sum equals $n^2(n+1)^2/4$.)

Comment: For rules handling asymptotic expressions, check out Hildebrand's "Short course in asymptotics" (on his webpage). In your case, you have a sum of $n$ terms, each of them $O(n^3)$, as it is a finite sum it is $n O(n^3)$, thus  $O(n^4)$.

Comment: Nice, I found the formula and with the formula it's quite easy. But with your technique you could do it for the same sum with i^k, where k is a natural number